# Soft question: What level of mathematics would Higher Algebra by Henry Sinclair be?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Currently I'm studying Geometry and Algebra 2. I'm currently reading Higher Algebra by Henry Sinclair. I've only done the first 14 problems in Chapter 1. Some of the problems are simple, while others are more difficult. I would like to know, with my current level of knowledge, if it's appropriate to tackle this book.

Comment: You mean *Higher Algebra* by H. S. Hall and S. R. Knight.

Comment: It was written for Victorian schoolboys....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general strategy, you can tackle almost any textbook if you allow yourself to skip difficult problems, either temporarily until later, or skip them completely. You don't need to know how to do everything immediately. As usual, you don't need to know everything in the textbook anyway. You get to decide what you think is worth knowing depending on your interests and your aesthetic sensibilites. There is usually more than one approach to solving problems and you decide what makes sense to you. As long as you are making progress in being able to solve problems, that is what can motivate you to continue. Also, don't hesitate to use more than one textbook at a time because different textbooks probably have different approaches.

The *Higher Algebra* by Hall and Knight contains late 19th century algebra material, but some portion of its contents are still worth knowing. Even Euler's [*Elements of Algebra*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elements_of_Algebra) has contents worth knowing and editions of it are still being published as recently as 2015.